# Defining two different extension to the User model

Tags: python, django

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,blank=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField()

class StoreProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to be able to login/authenticate a User either as a "store" or a "customer".

1. Is there a way to make this work with the above model?
2. I will also be looking at the `@login_required` decorator to differentiate between store that is logged in and a customer. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to login/authenticate a User either as a "store" or a "customer".
>
> Is there a way to make this work with the above model?

Yes, but.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

If you want to use the automatic features, you get one (single) Profile class object associated with a User.

If you don't want to use the automatic profile features, it will work just fine.  You won't be able to use the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting or the `get_profile()` method of
a `User`.    You'll be forced to write a lot of

```
try:
    CustomerProfile.objects.get( user=request.user )
except CustomerProfile.DoesNotExist:
    # hmmm.  Must be a Store, not a Customer.
```

It's not too bad, since it's mostly going to be one generic function to fetch the related
profile "the hard way".

> I will also be looking at the @login_required decorator to differentiate between store that is logged in and a customer. Any advice on how to proceed?

1. Add a `save()` method to each class which checks for the existence of the object object. If you attempt to create a CustomerProfile for a User, the CustomerProfile.save() will check for a StoreProfile and raise an exception if it exists.

   The two relationships are exclusive.  You need to assure this in your various models.
2. Write two decorators, you'll be happier.  They have a fair amount of overlap, but it's nicer to write many simple parameter-free decorators than to work up an uber-decorator.

   `@customer_required` and `@store_required`.  Each will do what `@login_required` does as well as determine which relationship with the User has a record.    customer_required must check for a CustomerProfile relationship with the User.  store_required checks for a StoreProfile relationship with the user.

---

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#groups

On the other hand, you have Groups defined within Django.  I'd recommend that you make use of the groups and the group names instead of trying to have super-fancy profiles like this.

Have one "master" Profile with all the attributes.

Use the Django Group table to define your various roles ("User", "Store") and allocate users to groups correctly.

Then check for the Group Name in your @store_required and @customer_required authorization decorators.

Comment: I didn't know about the Django Groups, I'll try and implement it. Thanks :)

Comment: I read about creating user groups, I think I have the general idea. For instance if I have these two statement: `store_group= Group(name='Store')` `store_group.save()`. Where in my django Project should I include them?

Comment: @Rami_H: Groups are seeded into your database once when you create the application.  There are fixtures for doing that.  Or you create them manually through the admin interface.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this can't be done. But you can try this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    store = OneToOneField(Store, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = OneToOneField(Customer, blank=True, null=True)
```

and set only one of `store` or `customer` when creating profile for user.

Comment: This is nice.   It may lead to a hair more DB access to validate the user on every single request.  If performance is a problem, then the Store and Customer attributes can be merged into the single UserProfile table and simple "flag" properties used to discriminate among users.

Comment: I think it is a really interesting approach. I am having a hard time differentiating between `OneToOneField` and `ForeignKey`. Can you explain why you chose `ForeignKey` with the user and `OneToOneField` with the store and customer?

Comment: I chose ForeignKey because I believe this is required way for using user profiles. I used OneToOneField for store and customer because there can be at most only on store or customer for a user profile.

Answer (score 0):

How you extend the User model with new foreign table needn't change how you approach this - so this is fine.

One way to approach this is to use the login_required logic, but also assign permissions in Django's authentication to users when they are created - one for store and one for customer.  Otherwise, you could just write a utility function to determine their membership based on their presence in the foreign table.  For more info, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/